# Como extrair conteúdo de uma Pagina PHP?

Tags: php, html

Pessoal eu basicamente estou tentando pegar uns dados da SEFAZ, para verificar se ela se encontra online ou indisponível no momento eu não estou conseguindo até porque eu não sei, gostaria de saber como eu posso está pegando um determinada linha do código deles ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a `get_http_response_code` para verificar se a página esta online e em seguida `file_get_contents` para fazer o download da página.

```
if(get_http_response_code('http://sefaz.com') != "200"){
    echo "erro";
}else{
    $pagina = file_get_contents('http://sefaz.com');
}
```

Para encontrar determinada linha após o download da página, neste caso a escolha do AP é pela conteudo da linha **MT** será utilizado a biblioteca `SIMPLE_HTML_DOM_PARSER`

```
<?php
    include '../../../library/Simple_HTML_DOM/simple_html_dom.php';
    $html = file_get_html( 'http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/disponibilidade.aspx?versao=0.00&tipoConteudo=Skeuqr8PQBY=' );
    $tdMT = NULL;
    foreach($html->find('td') as $td){
        if($td->innertext === 'MT'){
            $tdMT = $td->parent();
            foreach($tdMT->find('td') as $td){
                echo $td->innertext . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

O que está sendo feito:

1. É realizado a inclusão da biblioteca `Simple_HTML_DOM`
2. É feito o download total da página
3. É feito a busca por tags `td`
4. É feito uma checagem se a `td` é a desejada (no caso **MT**)
5. É feita a atribuição do elemento pai desta `td` no caso a `tr`
6. É Feita a impressão de todos os elementos presentes dentro das `td` filha da `tr` (poderia ser feito qualquer computação)

*Obs: Há alem de texto plano como **MT** e **-** tags HTML dentro das `td`.

Link para download da biblioteca: [Link](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: sim mas no entanto eu quero apenas, pegar um linha dentro do HTML DELE, Saka tipo eu quero a <div class="texte"> </div> um exemplo. como eu faço ?

Comment: sim isso  invés de ser o site inteiro eu quero apenas uma linha exemplo  <div class="texte"> <h1> status da sefaz : .......... </h1></div>

Comment: http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/disponibilidade.aspx?versao=0.00&tipoConteudo=Skeuqr8PQBY=                                                           entra nesse link eu quero pegar a linha Onde está escrito MT ela inteira

Comment: como assim vei nao entendi ?

Comment: @EdwardJunior Editei minha resposta, o site oficial esta offline momentaneamente posso fazer upload no dropbox da lib se quiser

Comment: @EdwardJunior fiz upload da lib no dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tzwpcv5zg7y1nr/simple_html_dom.php?dl=0

Comment: cara muito obrigado funcionou, mais eu te pergunto como eu posso fazer um IF NESSE Pra invés dele trazer tudo ele apenas meda uma resposta ATIVO OU INATIVO , Exemplo  Se ( a bola estiver verde ) ATIVO / Se Não (estiver bola verde) Inativo ?